# Android emulator doesn't work on MacOS Monterey?

Tags: android, android-studio, macos-monterey

I recently upgraded my Mac from MacOS Big Sur to Monterey. After doing so, I cannot get the Android emulator to run. It tries to start, but gets stuck on the "Connecting to the emulator" screen. It worked fine before I upgraded.

I tried wiping and cold-booting the emulator, as well as setting up a new one using the most recent system image, neither solved the problem.

I'm using the Bumblebee release of Android Studio and I made sure it is up to date. My Mac has the Apple M1 chip, so I am using arm64-v8a system images. I've tried both the S and the Sv2 image.

Has anyone else had this problem? What else can I do to try to solve it?

Comment: Hey there! Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I did, but I can't remember how, sorry. I may have removed an reinstalled the Bumblebee release.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install Android Studio, maybe android studio has kept files from the previous version of Mac OS witch is not compatible with the current version (I assume)